# Async def on_ready(): Discord bot Python troubleshooting needed

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to troubleshoot this issue for my python code but i have not been able to resolve it yet. Can anyone help please?

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=data['BotStatus']))
    print('bruh idek why im using python')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def redeem(ctx, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
    allowed_countries = [
     'US', 'GB', 'DE', 'CA', 'AU', 'IT', 'NZ', 'MX', 'BE', 'FR', 'ID', 'SG', 'BR', 'MY', 'PT', 'IL', 'DK', 'NL', 'ES', 'SE', 'NO', 'TR']
```

When I run the script. This is what i get.

I am currently using Python 2.7.10. If anyone can please help me troubleshoot this issue it would help me in numerous ways.

> File "bot.py", line 173
>       async def on_ready():
>           ^

Comment: There is just TOO much code, nobody is gonna read this, please give a Minimal, (Reproducible) example that show the problem, also point the line 173^^ And give the full stacktrace, you gave nothing to understand^^

Comment: Edit your post, never add important information in comment ;)

Comment: oh. ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) requires Python 3.5.3 or higher.  It cannot run on Python 2.  See the [Prerequisites section of the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#prerequisites)

> discord.py works with Python 3.5.3 or higher. Support for earlier versions of Python is not provided. Python 2.7 or lower is not supported. Python 3.4 or lower is not supported due to one of the dependencies ([aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)) not supporting Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to python 3.6.8, it works great for me.